# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<module.name>' - Installation error

Tags: python-3.x, module, virtualenv, mutagen, pythoninterpreter

I am building a desktop app  using Python and PySimpleGUI. So far, everything works just fine. Whilst I was working at the project, I realized I need to find a way to get the duration of some mp3 files and to display it in a certain way. I discovered mutagen module that is supposed to help me in this sense, I installed, and here the problem arise:

- It throws me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mutagen'`.
- Seeing this, I started to look for the problem, but I couldn't not understand why my interpretor did not find the module even though I Installed it CORRECTLY. (as PyCharm told me)

I have tried the following:

- I am using a local virtual environment that has installed the dependecies for the project(and some extra) and I uninstalled and installed the package 3-4 times
- I deleted the local virtual environment and I created another one. I installed the packages again and same issue.
- I installed a random module (scipy) and I tried to import it somewhere in the project and it thrown me same error, but this time for `scipy module`

My guess is that I did not configured properly my interpreter, but to be honest, I have no idea what I am doing wrong, because I followed the same steps I've been using for creating a venv with its according interpreter and for other projects, it worked just fine.

Further details:

- Using python3.9 base .exe
- I installed the packages in two ways: one using the pycharm IDE, and one by running `pip3 install mutagen`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be using a different `pip` that is not the one that affects the Python you are using. Instead of using

```
pip install mutagen
```

Consider using `pip` as a module of the Python you are using:

```
python -m pip install mutagen
```

This way you'll be sure you are working on the same Python.

If you want to continue using plain `pip`, try `which python` and `which pip` to make sure they are referencing the same environment.

Comment: oh man.. what a newbie mistake. That is true. I installed the package using your command and it works. Thanks a bunch mate! You saved me! :D Good luck!